# Any way to make prompts and previous-output uneditable in shell/term-mode?

Tags: shell, ansi-term

This is admittedly a superficial question.

Although `ansi-term` starts out behaving correctly when I first open it, it seems to degrade into an 'editable' mode after a few commands, e.g., when I do `C-a` (start of line) followed by `C-k` (kill line), it wipes out the whole prompt.

For my aesthetic sanity, is there any way to make the prompts and previous output uneditable (for `shell`)?  (Updated to exclude ansi-term given the meaningful differences.)

I'm using zsh in Emacs 24.4; OS is LXDE (Ubuntu 14.04) via Virtual Box.

(Ideally I'd still be able to move my cursor around...)

Comment: Are you on an "odd" OS by any chance? Usually in shell-mode C-a jumps to the start of the commandline, *after* the prompt, and a second C-a is required to jump to the very start. On Windows and Solaris (in a former life) I usually found that C-a jumped to the very start, wheras on MacOS, Linux etc. it works as expected for me.

Comment: @Mark A: I've updated the original post to include a few more details, including my current set-up.

Comment: The described behaviour of ansi-term sounds like you've switched to line mode by either a weird default or `C-c C-j`. Try finding out that default or switch to char mode with `C-c C-k`.

Comment: Since `shell-mode` / `term-mode` respectively do / do not derive from `comint-mode`, you're asking two very different questions at the same time here.  Mind splitting this into two separate questions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[comint](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode)-derived modes (like `shell`, `ielm`, ...) support filter functions, the following snippet makes the output and prompt read-only:

```
(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)

(defun my-comint-preoutput-turn-buffer-read-only (text)
  (propertize text 'read-only t))

(add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions 'my-comint-preoutput-turn-buffer-read-only)
```

As for `ansi-term` (which is not derived from [comint](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode)), it features two modes of operation, `char mode` which stays as truthful to the bindings of the shell and the software running in it as possible and `line mode` which allows you to edit the buffer as you please. You should generally stay in `char mode` (bound to `C-c C-k`) and occasionally switch to `line mode` (bound to `C-c C-j`) for editing command output.

Comment: This was really pretty, but stopped working… :( I have a working solution that takes considerably more code → https://github.com/michalrus/dotfiles/commit/bd2e0ee668b99d88cd9296381176f41d8027c127

Comment: Dunno, still works for me on 25.2.

Comment: It does in a sense, that you cannot delete this text, but you can insert new, interleaving with that immutable one.

Comment: I see, didn't test that specifically.

Comment: Oops, one more change for anyone looking. I missed some loopholes before. This one works perfectly for me. https://github.com/michalrus/dotfiles/blob/c4421e361400c4184ea90a021254766372a1f301/.emacs.d/init.d/040-terminal.el.symlink#L26-L48

Answer (score 2):

When mixing `term` with `shell-mode`, the variable `comint-use-prompt-regexp` seems to get set occasionally.  This causes behavior a bit like you've described: in *shell-mode* <kbd>C-a</kbd> will go to the beginning of the line, <kbd>C-k</kbd> will kill the whole line, including prompt.

A simple fix is to reset `comint-use-prompt-regexp` with <kbd>C-: (setq comint-use-prompt-regexp nil)</kbd>, forcing shell mode to use text properties which cursor movement keys are aware of.

There's a description of how this works in the GNU Emacs manual here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Prompts.html

Answer (score 1):

Try customizing the variable `comint-prompt-read-only` to `t`.

This will affect `shell-mode` and others derived from `comint-mode`, but not `term-mode`.