# Prompt can be be deleted in run-scheme but not in run-python?

Tags: shell, comint, scheme

Prompt can be deleted when I do a run-scheme but not in run-python. Is there a way to make it standard i.e not to delete the prompts? I checked the comint-mode manual but couldn't find anything that controlled this behavior.

Are there any advantages using comint over ansi-term? I am thinking if I should stick with ansi-term because the default behaviour is better. Only problem I have is to sync with my source code in a correct way (other than hacks like copy paste the clipboard etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I can't reproduce this in `emacs -Q`, the prompts can be deleted for both Scheme and Python buffers.  Customizing `comint-prompt-read-only` gives me a read-only prompt for both again.
2. `ansi-term` is much slower as it emulates a full terminal, should behave correctly and is less Emacs-like (captures more keys, harder to customize).  `comint`-derived modes on the other hand are more light-weight, have their basic behaviour in common and can be customized to have extra features you need.

Comment: It is like you said in Emacs 24.5. I am using 25.0.5 compiled on my machine. Oddly its just the prompt ">>>" that is readonly in the case of python and "=>" in the case of ipython. Its also colored differently. Other texts are free and deletable. >>> appears three times in 24.5 on the same line and is deletable. Wonder if we can restrict parts of text like that? And apparently something has changed in 25.0.0?

Comment: See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2897/10 for turning it all read-only.  The stray prompts are Emacs sending extra commands to subprocesses and getting it back, but there's [no proper way around that](http://emacshorrors.com/post/master-command-interpreter).

Comment: Thanks - those stray prompts doesn't appear in 25.0.5.50 but as exlpained you can see it behaves differently with Python and Scheme for not-so-clear reasons.

Comment: Feel free to report this unusual behaviour with `M-x report-emacs-bug` if it's not gone after rebuilding the latest git checkout.

Comment: Ok I will build with the latest git and see if the issue goes away or else submit a bug report.