# shell-mode: `C-a` moves point to beginning of line instead of after prompt

Tags: shell-mode

Usually `C-a` moves point to just after the prompt:

```
andreas@my-computer:~/some/folder
$ #here
```

but occasionally something happens and `C-a` starts to the beginning of line:

```
andreas@my-computer:~/some/folder
#here
```

I have no idea why this happens, and the only way I've been able to fix it is to restart Emacs. How can I revert `C-a` to the normal behavior of moving to the point after the prompt?

Comment: Check what function is bound to `C-a` both when it's working and when it isn't: you can do that with `C-h c C-a RET`. If they are different, that might provide a clue. Also, check that the mode is still `shell-mode` (e.g, with `C-h v major-mode RET`).

Comment: thanks @Nick, they're no different. another side effect is that `C-c C-c` doesn't work on long-running processes inside the shell, it fails with "Text is read only".

Comment: Maybe that's what you are doing: C-x C-q will toggle the read-only option on the buffer, so you may be pressing that inadvertently. The status line should tell you whether the buffer is read-only: if it is, try C-x C-q again to restore it to read-write But I can't reproduce the C-a behavior with just setting the buffer read-only.

Comment: Have you tried `M-x shell-mode RET` when it's in the funky state? Maybe that will restore the proper C-a behavior.

Comment: BTW, is C-a bound to  `comint-bol`?

Comment: thanks again @Nick! `M-x shell-mode` doesn't fix the funk. I can write when I'm positioned after the prompt, but it's read-only when I try to type on the `$` in the prompt, or on running shell output. `C-a` is bound to `move-beginning-of-line`

Comment: Ahhh I found the answer here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33766/9062

Comment: `(setq comint-use-prompt-regexp nil)` [fixed it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33766/9062)!

Comment: It was caused by [`ein:ipdb-buffer-initialize`](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/blob/3cdb353fe2fbe7f8bb6f64807a7262ab5f0eb92b/lisp/ein-ipdb.el#L144)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by invoking `(setq comint-use-prompt-regexp nil)`.

It was caused by [ein:ipdb-buffer-initialize](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/blob/3cdb353fe2fbe7f8bb6f64807a7262ab5f0eb92b/lisp/ein-ipdb.el#L144)

Comment: That variable already defaults to nil, so please expand your answer to include some explanation of why it was set otherwise in the first place.